# OATS OpenScript: How to capture the screenshot of a full page

Tags: oracle, openscript

I want to use OATS OpenScript to capture the screen shot of each page of the web app. For now I can get screen shot in "wait for page" node and I have tried the capturePage() method, however, both give me only part of the screen. What I want is to get the screen shot of the full page when the page content is very long. How can I achieve that in OpenScript? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Show something, how you're doing it?

Comment: Currently, I am using the following code:Boolean ret = web.window("/web:window[@index='0' or @title='default']").capturePage();

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Application Testing Suite aka OATS tool provides inbuilt function to capture screen shots which of Desktop/Laptop montior size  only

```
Web.window().CapturePage();
```

If you page is long and scrolling involved you may add logic to scroll page and capture screen again

```
Web.window().CapturePage();

Web.page().Scroll(100,100);

Web.window().CapturePage();
```

for more OATS tips follow the links
http://www.testinghive.com/category/oracle-application-testing-suite-tips

Answer (score 0):

currently, no API to directly capture all , pls raise a SR if you are Oracle customer